# Foundation 6.4.1 - grid has stopped working?

Tags: grid, zurb-foundation

Why has the grid system stopped working in 6.4.1? It was working in 6.3.1.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/css/foundation.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-2 columns">2 columns</div>
  <div class="medium-10 columns">10 columns</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-3 columns">3 columns</div>
  <div class="medium-9 columns">9 columns</div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the `XY Grid` is the new grid system to use with the version `6.4` ([Release notes](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/releases/)).

While the `float grid` is still supported as a legacy ([Foundation grids](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html)).